# Javascript + Thymeleaf doesn't find the form

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

On the input form, I perform a check of the entered cost value. But running the script can't find the form input input01.

That's how it works:

```html
<form name="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
        <input type="text" name="input01">
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function check() {
            let inputVal = document.forms["form01"]["input01"].value;
            OK!!!
            ....
        }
    </script>
```

But not like this:

```html
<form name="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
        <input type="text" name="input01" th:field="*{cost}">
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function check() {
            let inputVal = document.forms["form01"]["input01"].value;
            Where Error:
            "Uncaught TypeError: document.forms.form01.input01 is undefined"

            ....
        }
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html,

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<input type="text" id="datePlanted" name="datePlanted" th:value="*{datePlanted}" />
```

Hence when you add `th:field="*{cost}"`, the form element name and id is getting changed to `name="cost" id="cost"`. so document.forms["form01"]s input element will look like

`<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost">`

Either access the element as

`document.forms["form01"]["cost"]`

Or add a form id like below and your existing code should work.

`<input id="input01" type="text" name="input01" th:field="*{cost}">`.

Hope that helps to solve your problem.